# Is there a mathematical term to refer to the number of unique elements in a multiset/sequence/tuple?

Tags: terminology

Does there exist a mathematical term to refer to the number of unique elements in a multiset/sequence/tuple? For example, if a tuple $T$ is $[2, 4, 2, 10, 4, 8, 10]$, then the number of unique elements in $T$ is $4$: $$[2, 4, 8, 10].$$ The term “cardinality” is not suitable because, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), if $M = \{a, a, b, b, b, c\}$ is a multiset, then its cardinality is $6$, although the number of unique elements in $M$ is $3$:$$\{a, b, c\}.$$

Comment: I'd likely just call it the 'number of distinct elements', or perhaps the 'cardinality of the range'.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the term “dimension” may be suitable here ([source](http://oeis.org/wiki/Multisets)):

> The *root set* (or *support set*) of a multiset is the set of its distinct elements. The *dimension* of a multiset is the [cardinality](http://oeis.org/wiki/Cardinality) of the support set.